# Debug Assertion Failed (invalid null pointer) default string parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

The following code

```
void f(const std::string &s = {}) {
}

f();
```

Produces a `Debug Assertion Failed (invalid null pointer)` in Visual Studio 2013 (debug build). It runs ok in gcc (i can get `s.length()` as 0). It looks like an error when trying to construct `s`:

Here is the call stack:

frame:

```
f(); <-- HERE --
```

frame (xstring):

```
basic_string(const _Elem *_Ptr)
  : _Mybase()
  { // construct from [_Ptr, <null>)
  _Tidy();
  assign(_Ptr); // <-- HERE --
  }
```

frame (xstring):

```
_Myt& assign(const _Elem *_Ptr)
  { // assign [_Ptr, <null>)
  _DEBUG_POINTER(_Ptr); <-- HERE --
  return (assign(_Ptr, _Traits::length(_Ptr)));
  }
```

frame (xutility):

```
template<class _Ty> inline
  void _Debug_pointer(const _Ty *_First, _Dbfile_t _File, _Dbline_t _Line)
  { // test iterator for non-singularity, const pointers
  if (_First == 0)
    _DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid null pointer", _File, _Line); <-- HERE --
  }
```

It looks like it calls the constructor with `(const char *)` instead of the default constructor.

When I tried this:

```
std::string x = {}; // local variable
```

It calls the default constructor.

Is this a bug on Visual Studio or am I missing something?

I know a workaround would be `void f(const std::string &s = "")`, but I wanted to use default initializer and it is a very strange behaviour.

Comment: `f();` is invalid, you can't have non-declarations outside of functions.

Comment: @MattMcNabb it's a call in main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug.

If it wasn't a bug then you should get ambiguous constructor error, since the constructor that's called isn't the default constructor, and the default constructor could be called.

The following code compiles with Visual C++ 12.0 (the compiler shipped with Visual Studio 2013):

```
struct X
{
    X( char const* ) {}
};

void g( X const& = {} ) {}
```

It should not compile.

The following code, where the constructor argument is not default-constructible, fails to compile:

```
struct Y
{
    struct E { E( int ){} };
    Y( E ) {}
};

void h( Y const& = {} ) {}
```

An intermediate case with the constructor argument of enumeration type does compile, so apparently the initializer `{}` is not transformed to `{0}`, but to `{{}}` – if I may get speculative, perhaps in order to suppress warnings for initialization of `std::array`?

---

I've submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/875119/c-11-empty-initializer-invoking-incorrect-constructor) to Microsoft.